# Difference between node and partition in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm new to Apache Cassandra. While reading about it, I found in following paragraph that node and partition do not mean the same.

> One suggested measure of whether a secondary index is warranted is whether the number of partitions is approximately equal to number of nodes in cluster. Mathematically this seem to offer a balance of speeding up the reads rather than slowing them down.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 3):

The number of partitions is the number of buckets you can split your data into by unique values of your indexed columns.  So, for example, if you index on sex, you'll get two partitions: male and female.  If you index on US states, you'll get 50.  If you index on email, you may get the # of partitions comparable to the number of rows in the table. The guideline specifies that the performance is best when the number of unique values in the indexed column is the same as the number of nodes.